# Draw a sequence of Android objects with a time interval between

Tags: android, imageview, delay, sleep

I have a program which automatically moves objects around the screen, drawing them on an ImageView. On some occasions, two or more objects will be moved in succession. At present, the user sees only the final configuration. I would like to insert a pause between them, so that intermediate configurations are seen.
The code below is intended to achieve this by setting a busy flag and sleeping on a separate thread. However, it does not update the screen in between. The effect is a long pause followed by the final view.
Advice would be welcome!

```
private boolean busy = false;
private void slowMoveObject(<args>) {
    Thread th = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            int waitCount = 0;
            while (busy) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                waitCount++;
                if (waitCount > 50) break;
            }
            busy = true;
            moveObject(<args>);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            busy = false;
        };
    };
    th.run(); // delay

}
```

Comment: You can't update the UI on a background thread. You will have to find a way to post your moveObject call to the UI thread using a handler of some sorts. Also, calling run() on a Thread runs it synchronously which will block the UI thread until it completes.

Comment: Thanks for these tips - they explain why it did not work. I will look again at it in the light of these. Roger